# How to check if a char array element is empty?

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I have on very simple array in C#:

```
char[] niz = new char[16];
niz[0] = 'c';
niz[1] = 's';
niz[2] = 'h';
niz[3] = 'a';
niz[4] = 'r';
niz[5] = 'p';
```

How can I check which element of this array is empty?

I've tried this code:

```
if (niz[6] == null) Console.WriteLine("6th is empty");
```

But in this case it's not empty, and I don't know why.

Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) types. change this to

```
char?[] niz = new char?[16];
```

then your code will work

```
if (!niz[6].HasValue) 
  Console.WriteLine("6th is empty");
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `!niz[6].HasValue`

Answer (score 6):

Array will be initialized with default values of array element type. Char is not a reference type, so `null` is not default value for it. For char default is `0`.

You can check `array[i] == default(char)`, but this will not tell you if array item is empty, or it has default value assigned by you:

```
char[] niz = new char[16];
niz[0] = 'c';
niz[1] = (char)0; // default value
niz[2] = '\0'; // default value
niz[3] = 'a';
niz[4] = 'r';
niz[5] = 'p';

for(int i = 0; i < niz.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(niz[i] == default(char));
```

As Ehsan suggested, you can use array of nullable chars, but again, you will not know whether item is not initialized, or you have assigned `null` value to it. I suggest you to use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class instead of array. It will contain only items you need (i.e. no default empty items).

Comment: Is it true to say that `default(char)` should be used in case of generics and instead it should be `HasValue` ?

Comment: @PKKG if you are using generic array, then use `default(T)` instead of `default(char)`

Comment: can you please clarify one point about the usage priority in this context? `Hasvalue` or `default(char)`

Comment: @PKKG sorry, don't get what you are asking about. `HasValue` is for `Nullable<T>` type.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using chars, you need to say:

if (niz[6] == '\0') Console.WriteLine("6th is empty");

Chars cannot be equal to null.

Comment: It should be `'\0'` and not `'0'`

Comment: Woops, will change it now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that char will be initialized with a default value. You need to make it nullable like this:

```
char?[] niz = new char?[16];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 char[] niz = new char[16];
        niz[0] = 'c';
        niz[1] = 's';
        niz[2] = 'h';
        niz[3] = 'a';
        niz[4] = 'r';
        niz[5] = 'p';
        for (int i = 0; i < niz.Length; i++)
        {
            if (niz[i] == '\0') Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```